# Map Ctrl+P to another key programmatically

Tags: keyboard

I want to map the key command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to a single key so that I can label it for easy access for our Kiosks. I would in particular like a way to do this programmatically via command line. This is going to be for our Kiosk machines we run on Pis. Frankly, I thought that would be very easy, but I seem to be having a very difficult time finding a simple way to do this.

Any guidance, suggestions would be very much appreciated.

This is specifically in raspbian using ubuntu-mate, although I am not booting into a full desktop, only using metacity.

I would like to program another key (<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, not sure which key yet) to deliver the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> command sequence. For example, if I decide to use the Home key, when I press home, I want to bring up the print dialog.

Comment: What "key command"? For what program? What is this shortcut supposed to do? In what desktop environment? What version of Ubuntu? Which flavor of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts